# mclust: how can I make this work

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

Here is my code:

```
> dim(clustering)
[1] 234  31

> library(mclust)
> em_c <- Mclust(clustering[,2:31])
Warning messages:
1: In summary.mclustBIC(Bic, data, G = G, modelNames = modelNames) :
  best model occurs at the min or max # of components considered
2: In Mclust(clustering[, 2:31]) :
  optimal number of clusters occurs at min choice
> em_c
'Mclust' model object:
best model: elliposidal multivariate normal (XXX) with 1 components
```

I don't get what's causing the problem, If you have any insights please let me know.
And thanks.

Comment: Without seeing the data, it is difficult to try out. Couldn't you give the head of the first 5 variables?

Comment: ete hiver ddist sens city1_longitude city1_latitude city2_longitude ....

they are all numeric data

Comment: install.packages("mclust");
require(mclust);
a <- matrix(jitter(1:15),ncol=3);
model <- Mclust(a);
summary(model); e.g. this gives also only 1 component, so what is your problem? I meant, couldn't you provide a bit of your data? If not it is difficult to infer what your problem is (a model having only 1 component is not per se an error)

Comment: You have no `Error` messages, so `Mclust` completed its task successfully (by its own criteria).  Whether you got the answer you expected is another issue.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it "worked". Except that your data might only have a single "cluster" with respect to the way Mclust tries to model the data. I'm putting quotation marks around "cluster", because your data just might not be well representable using Gaussian mixtures.

The warning just emphasizes that you need to carefully evaluate your result, e.g. using visualization. Because of all the number of components it tried, the best result was at 2 components - it didn't try a single-component, but it might score even higher to actually *not* cluster your data.